# Riddle about a big family

Tags: riddle

We are a big family.
We are of alien origin, but bear Latin names.
We are all descendants from one, but some of us are born "in vitro".
Our 101st family member, although is not noble, and is not "the one", is the one that united us as a family.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're

> the chemical elements.

Reason:

> There are very many of them; humans did not make them; many have names derived from Latin; each is made from fusion of hydrogen; some are made in the lab; and finally, the 101st element, Mendelevium, is not a noble gas, but its namesake (Dmitri Mendeleev) was the one to make a periodic table like the one we use today.

Comment: Nice! Was thinking the same, but I could not think of any explanation for the fourth line.

Comment: i have been written half of my answer then i saw someone has answered ..btw +1

Comment: Even if you have the advantage of being in a chemistry class in the past year...great job.